# Python Script in WebApp won't run on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I recently deployed a NodeJS web app to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. However, the python script that is supposed to run on deployment doesn't run? When I every I run my app locally the script runs, but for some reason this isn't the case on Bean Stalk. The logs also don't indicate any type of error on the Python Script. Below is the code I used to run my python script in my app.js file:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["bitmexbot.py"]); // run python script
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm if Py installed on the instance?

Comment: Where do I go to do that?

Comment: Log into the instance created by Beanstalk via SSH and the key you provided. If you haven't provided a key then I would suggest starting an instance with the same AMI ID assign a key and check.